# How can we execute Oracle sequence in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, oracle-fdw

In between migration from Oracle to Postgres, I need to execute some insert statement for an Oracle table from Postgres (in which the primary key field is using a sequence for uniqueness).

Now at the time of the migration I am converting some procedure that is used to insert a row in a table, but I can't move table directly from oracle to Postgres due to a higher dependency on the table.

That's why I need to execute an Oracle sequence from Postgres.

Comment: Please add some more detail and/or code to your question to make it concrete.  Not sure what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to create a view in Oracle that doesn't contain the column that is to be filled from the sequence.

Then define a trigger on the table that fills the column from the sequence when NULL and creare a foreign table on the view.

Wheb you `INSERT` into the foreign table, the column will get filled by the trigger.

Comment: You don't really need the view - the trigger could simply ignore any value supplied for that column or check for NULL and only then use the sequence

Comment: Sure, that's an option if you never want to explicitly fill the column.